# Android main activity still the old one. How to set new?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, program-entry-point

I am trying to learn Android.

I simply have Splash.Java and MainActivity.Java classes.

Before Splash.Java was the starting Action of my application.
Now I want to change it to MainActivity.Java.

Here is what I have done:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main">            
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.anddappp.SPLASH" />
            <category android:name="com.example.anddappp.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I cleaned my Project, and I do not use "Run previously launched application" in Eclipse. But still the application starts with Splash.JAVA.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check in Run configuration which Activity is selected.

Comment: Thank you, but why did you add this as a comment rather than an answer? I want to pick this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Check in run configuration which activity is selected." This way android, or in this case eclipse knows which of your activities to start from.

In the future, if you know the answer to one of your questions feel free to answer it yourself. You will be able to accept your own answer in eight hours.

Thanks to shashank Kane for providing the answer